# How to find a Github file 's SHA blob

Tags: git, github, sha, github-api

I'm using this API to update a file on my repo, it requires me to have a valid SHA blob for a file that I want to update:

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/

How do I find the SHA blob for the specific file? Supposed in my testrepo in the test account here, what is the SHA blob for the test.txt file?

https://github.com/testacc01/testrepo01

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The docs for updating a file specify that you will need to provide the SHA for the file you will be replacing. The easiest way would be to query github for that, too. For example:

```
> curl https://api.github.com/repos/testacc01/testrepo01/contents/test.txt
{
  "name": "test.txt",
  "path": "test.txt",
  "sha": "4f8a0fd8ab3537b85a64dcffa1487f4196164d78",
  "size": 13,
 …
```

So, you can see what the SHA is in the "sha" field of the JSON response. Use that when you formulate your request to update the file with a new version. After you have successfully updated the file, the file will have a new SHA that you will need to request before it can be updated again. (Unless, I guess, your next update goes on a different branch.)

Comment: thanks that works for me, I forget that the SHA will be automatically updated after the file is updated.

Comment: I wasn't able to find in GitHub's v3 API docs which specific SHA hashing function they're using to generate these - SHA1, SHA256, etc (so that I could verify the file contents against them myself).  I believe git uses SHA-1 for commit hashes but it was unclear to me which hashing function GitHub is using for hashing file contents.  I've opened a ticket with them requesting this information.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston Hi, Did you get any response from github?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure.  I searched my email for it but I didn't find a reply from GitHub.

Comment: Regarding the SHA hashing function used: https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/#get-a-blob states that `[t]he file's SHA-1 hash is computed and stored in the blob object`. So it's SHA-1.

Comment: Using get repository contents to obtain the SHA of a file doesn't work if the file is larger than 1MB: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-repository-content

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to hit the api, you could generate the SHA yourself. Git generates the SHA by concatenating a header in the form of `blob {content.length} {null byte}` and the contents of your file. For example:

```
content = "what is up, doc?"
header = "blob #{content.bytesize}\0"
combined = header + content # will be "blob 16\u0000what is up, doc?"
sha1 = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(combined)
```

Source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: Might be useful to mention that this is Ruby code. :)

Answer (score 7):

If you use [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/), you can use the following to find the sha of a specific file :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "testacc01", name: "testrepo01") {
    object(expression: "master:test.txt") {
      ... on Blob {
        oid
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?variables=%7B%7D&query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22testacc01%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22testrepo01%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20object(expression%3A%20%22master%3Atest.txt%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Blob%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oid%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 4):

Using [Octokit Rest API](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/):

```js
import { Octokit } from "@octokit/rest";
    
const { data: { sha } } = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{file_path}', {
  owner: "owner-name",
  repo: "repo-name",
  file_path: "file-path-with-extension-from-root"
});
```

Comment: This will fetch the whole file content

Comment: I couldn't find a way to only get the SHA of a file, but this at least works, though I had to put it in try catch since if file is not found it throws an error.