# 403 error from Github.js getSha for files above ~1MB in size

Tags: javascript, github, github-api, http-status-code-403, github.js

I'm getting a 403 error when I try to use [Github.js](https://github.com/github-tools/github) to getSha (and subsequently getBlob) from files larger than ~1MB. Is there a limit to the file size? The code is below:

```
var gh = new GitHub({
    username: username,
    password: password
});

// get the repo from github
var repo = gh.getRepo('some-username','name-of-repo');

// get promise
repo.getSha('some-branch', 'some-file.json').then(function(result){

  // pass the sha onto getBlob
  return repo.getBlob(result.data.sha);

}).then(function(result){

  do_something_with_blob(result.data);

});
```

The GitHub API says that it supports blobs up to 100MB in size and I could not find anything about filesize limits in the [Github.js docs](http://github-tools.github.io/github/docs/3.1.0/Repository.html#getBlob). Also, the files are from a private Github repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It throws a `403 Forbidden` error because it uses [Github GET contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) which gives results for file not exceding 1Mo. For instance the following will throw 403 :

https://api.github.com/repos/bertrandmartel/w230st-osx/contents/CLOVER/tools/Shell64.efi?ref=master

Using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26203603/2614364) using GET tree API, you can get the file sha without downloading the whole file and then use `repo.getBlob` (which uses [Get blob API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/#get-a-blob) for file not exceding 100Mo).

The following example will get the tree for the parent folder of the specified file (for a file exceding 1Mo) with the GET trees api, filter the specific file by name and then request blob data :

```
const accessToken = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';

const gh = new GitHub({
  token: accessToken
});

const username = 'bertrandmartel';
const repoName = 'w230st-osx';
const branchName = 'master';
const filePath = 'CLOVER/tools/Shell64.efi'

var fileName = filePath.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
var fileParent = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf("/"));

var repo = gh.getRepo(username, repoName);

fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/' +
  username + '/' +
  repoName + '/git/trees/' +
  encodeURI(branchName + ':' + fileParent), {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "token " + accessToken
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(content) {
  var file = content.tree.filter(entry => entry.path === fileName);

  if (file.length > 0) {
    console.log("get blob for sha " + file[0].sha);
    //now get the blob
    repo.getBlob(file[0].sha).then(function(response) {
      console.log("response size : " + response.data.length);
    });
  } else {
    console.log("file " + fileName + " not found");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works for public repos but I can not seem to get the tree (using fetch) for private repos where I'm getting a 404 error. I'm guessing that is because fetch is not passing any authentication token along. Is there a way to pass the token using Fetch or get the tree using a method in the gh object that already has the token?

Comment: @NickFernandez I've updated the answer with addition of Authorization header in fetch options

Comment: @maugch where is it?

Comment: Note: the Get Content API now (May 2022) [supports raw files up to 100MB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72108664/6309)