# Is there a way to get binary files (contents) of Github private repositories of GitHub OAuth logged in users through Github API?

Tags: rest, github, github-api, github-oauth

I've been looking for a way to get binary files (contents) of Github private repositories and organization repositories through GitHub API, in order to build those files and deploy them for users. (in order to create a minimized version of clone deployment service)

It seems it is able to get binary files from Github releases through Github API. However, couldn't find a way to get files (contents) of repositories (not releases).

Is there any way to get contents of Github repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the content of a file (not a release), you would need to combine:

- [API Get Content](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#get-repository-content) to [get its SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20208173/6309)
- [API Get Blob](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/blobs#get-a-blob)

But only if your file is less than 1MB. For larger file, you [would need GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64758978/6309).

---

The [OP Tae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19452454/tae) opted for, in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74133940/is-there-a-way-to-get-binary-files-contents-of-github-private-repositories-of/74135068#comment130987533_74135068):

> just get the `clone_url` and then run `git clone`, rather than somehow getting all the blobs in order to to create directories and files again.

Comment: Thanks! In the end, I thought it'd be better to just get the `clone_url` and then run `git clone`, rather than somehow getting all the blobs in order to to create directories and files again. @VonC

Comment: @Tae Great, well done!